# R Magick package blank image with custom density

Tags: r, imagemagick

I'm trying to set a blank image with 300x300 resolution. However the following command does not seem to do it.

```
> image_1 <- image_blank(width = canvas_width, height= 10635, color = "none", defines = c('density' = '300'))
> image_1
# A tibble: 1 x 7
  format width height colorspace matte filesize density
  <chr>  <int>  <int> <chr>      <lgl>    <int> <chr>  
1 png     3630  10635 sRGB       TRUE         0 72x72
```

How do I set the density and if possible, make it a pdf not a png?

Comment: Based on my reading of the source code (ie `magick:::magick_image_blank`), you cannot. The [`-density` option](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php) is separate from the `-defines` option, and this isn't implemented in `magick`.

Comment: I do not know R Magick. But can you not just do `image_blank(width = canvas_width, height= 10635, color = "none", density = '300'))`